# Unable to get the Response from angular7 services in production environment

Tags: angular7, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I am new to angular and developed an angular application using angular CLI 7.
When I am running the application from my local system, I am getting the response from the service and it is working fine.

But when I deployed the application in the production server, I am unable to get the response from the service. Service is taking too long to respond and getting the HTTPErrorResponse of status Unknown Error.

We are using the Spring microservices for api calls to get the response data.

I am using the proxy.conf.json for the services because the URL running angular app is different from the service.

proxy.conf.json:

```
{
   "/api/*":{
       "target":"http://wsd185erd986.test.com/api",
       "secure":false,
       "loglevel":debug,
       "changeOrigin":true
    }
}
```

Changed the package.json to include the proxy.conf.json in proxyConfig.
Include the response headers in the service.

Could any one know on how to configure these proxy settings in production build for angular. Do we need to include any headers in the service calls.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTPErrorResponse  - A response that represents an error or failure,
>   either from a non-successful HTTP status, an error while executing the
>   request, or some other failure which occurred during the parsing of
>   the response.

So as per the docs this error is thrown in multiple cases either there is an error at server end and server send the error response or there was some issue in parsing.

Please check the Spring Boot API request logs to see what response code is sent back.
You can check the API by a standalone client too (like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)) and see if there is some issue.

As an aside - you should not be using angular development server in production as it is meant for angular development. Typically you can use any web server ( like Apache, NGinx etc) to host your angular production files ( they are merely static resources) and then either use them as a proxy ( by having their proxy configuration) or have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) enabled services.

Comment: From my local system, the services are working fine. Also, we checked the logs from service apis. Issue is with a\from angular ui.

Comment: Via Angular code you can log the response you are receiving in browser console and check is the content correctly formatted.

Comment: Kept the browser logs and came to know the status as Unknown error..
Do we need to change any config settings in production build of angular ?

Comment: Are you able to see correct response in the browser network tab ( press F12)